# Dependency Injection in JHipster with Mybatis

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, mybatis, jhipster

I have little problem with Spring and Mybatis connection in JHipster framework( (out of the box).

Problem is occurred when I try inject class, which have Mybatis mapper injected. In this situation class returns null pointer exception. When I try to autowire this class I get "cannot find candidate to autowire error".

**Architecture of class:**
Repository(Mybatis mapper interface) ->
ServiceImplementation (Class with injected Mybatis Repository, business logic) -> 
Resource (REST controller with instance of Service)

I think solution is simple, but I cannot find right implementation:

- Service Implementation is invisible for Spring Beans Mapper and I
  can't find in JHipster configuration for them.
- I have to use another annotation to get right injection of Service
  Implemenation

Somebody meet with this situation and can get litte clue for me to refactor my code? :-) Thanks

Code:

Repository

```
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Insert;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Delete;


import pl.xxx.xxx.domain.City;
import pl.xxx.xxx.domain.Dish;

@Mapper
public interface CityMapper {

    @Select("SELECT * FROM CITY WHERE id = #{id}")
    City getCityByID(@Param("id") Long id);

    @Select("SELECT * FROM CITY WHERE name = #{name}")
    City getCityByName(@Param("name") String name);

    @Insert("INSERT INTO CITY('name') VALUES(#{name})")
    void createCity(City city);

    @Delete("DELETE FROM CITY WHERE id = #{id}")
    void deleteCityByID(City city);

    @Select("SELECT count(*) FROM CITY")
    int getNumberOfCities();

    @Select("<script>"
            + "SELECT * FROM CITY "
            + "</script>")
    List<City> findAll();

}
```

Service

package pl.xxx.xxx.service.impl;

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import pl.xxxx.xxxx.domain.City;
import pl.xxxx.xxx.repository.CityMapper;
import pl.xxx.xxx.service.CityService;
import pl.xxx.xxx.web.rest.util.Pageable;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;


@Service
@Transactional
public class CityServiceImpl implements CityService {

    @Inject
    private CityMapper cityMapper;

    @Override
    public List<City> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return cityMapper.findAll();
    }

}
```

Interface

```
package pl.xxx.xxx.service;

import java.util.List;

import pl.xxx.xxx.domain.City;
import pl.xxxx.xxx.domain.Dish;
import pl.xxx.xxx.web.rest.util.Pageable;

public interface CityService {
    /**
     *  Get all the dishes.
     *  
     *  @param pageable the pagination information
     *  @return the list of entities
     */
    List<City> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Resource

```
package pl.xxx.xxxx.web.rest;

import com.codahale.metrics.annotation.Timed;
import pl.xxx.xxx.xxx.City;
import pl.xxx.xxx.domain.Dish;
import pl.xxx.xxx.repository.CityMapper;
import pl.xxx.xxx.service.impl.CityServiceImpl;

import pl.xxx.xxx.web.rest.util.Pageable;
import pl.xxx.xxx.web.rest.util.PaginationUtil;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.*;

/**
 * REST controller for managing City.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CityResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CityResource.class);

    private CityServiceImpl cityServiceImpl;

    @Inject 
    private CityMapper cityMapper;


    /**
     * GET  /Cities: get all the cities.
     *
     * @param pageable the pagination information
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and the list of citires in body
     * @throws URISyntaxException if there is an error to generate the pagination HTTP getHeaders()
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/cities",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)        
    @Timed()
    public ResponseEntity<List<City>> getAllCities(Pageable pageable)
        throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Cities");
        Pageable p = new Pageable();
        List<City> page = cityServiceImpl.findAll(p); 
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generateSearchPaginationHttpHeadersLM("/api/cities");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(page, headers, HttpStatus.OK);        
    }

}
```

Comment: JHipster is not a framework.

Comment: Ok i find solution for this problem. In resource i change injection from class "    private CityServiceImpl cityServiceImpl;"  to interface " @Inject
    private CityService cityServiceImpl;"  Now system inject right class and business layer is still stored in cityServiceImpl.